# Prefix-concatenate in SQL for prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

How do i concatenate in jdbc sql? For example. I want the title to have a string/characters before it. So it would be like `"0001-title"`. I want that value to be stored inside a variable so that i can easily change it. I also what the value to be increment for over a time.  Is there a way on how to do this?

Here's what i've tried so far but no luck. please help!

```
public void update(String title, String artist, String album){
 String SQL = "INSERT INTO music(title, artist, album) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, title, artist, album);
return;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your question, the code you show you tried has nothing for concatenation. Now, for simple SQL you can use the CONCAT function, ex: CONCAT('0001-', 'title)' will return "0001-title". If not, can't you simply concatenate the strings in a variable before the statement and simply insert the data already concatenated?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the prefix parameter into you INSERT query and use CONCAT function to join the title with prefix. All you need just add title as well as prefix.

```
public void update(String title, String artist, String album){
  String SQL = "INSERT INTO music(title, artist, album) VALUES(CONCAT(?,?), ?, ?);
  jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, "0001-", title, artist, album);
}
```

Depending on DB you can also define a trigger for the music table and updte the title on fly just in the insert moment.